# EditText & TextView textColorPrimary does not follow Theme color for API < 21

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

There some issue in styling the Toolbar view to make it work for both API 21 and below but consider I have this styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customized theme for API < 21 -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/grey</item>
</style>
```

and this in my screen1.xml Toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/AppToolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppPopupToolbarTheme"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_text"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <!-- other views here -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The `"?android:textColorPrimary"` above does not work in API < 21 and fall back to dark text color instead of my `@color/white`.

However I still believe it possible since "auto-generated" TextView title by using `setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar));` in `Activity.onCreate()`, I can see the TextView follow my `textColorPrimary`.

1. What should be in the `android:textColor=`? or
2. how can I see the generated TextView from ActionBar support (like browser F12)? so I can apply the same.

Comment: You should be using `?textColorPrimary`. On API < 21, `textColorPrimary` is provided by AppCompat. Library attributes do not require the `android:` prefix.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work at least for API19. Now, I just define a style that use my defined color and assign the style to the `TextView`. I think this is a bug, since only `android:textColorPrimary` not working but `android:background` working fine.

Answer (score 4):

The proper value for the textcolor attribute should be:

```
android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
```